# Fourier transforms having compact support

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

As we know, the fourier transform is a map $\mathcal{F}:L^1\rightarrow C_0$ (all with domain $\mathbb{R}$). Can one characterize the space of $f\in L^1$ such that $\mathcal{F}$ has compact support, i.e. is in $C_c\subset C_0$? In particular, is this space dense in $L^1$? I believe this should be true, but I find it hard to come up with nontrivial examples of such $f$. I guess the formula $\mathcal{F}(f\ast g)=\mathcal{F}(f)\mathcal{F}(g)$ should be useful?

Comment: One can characterize the space by a Paley-Weiner type condition: $\hat f$ has compact support if and only if $f$ is the restriction to $\Bbb R$ of an entire function $g\in H(\Bbb C)$ such that $|g(x+iy)|\le c\exp(A|y|)$. I don't see how this characterization helps showing the space is dense. Your "guess" sounds like a hint from somewhere, making this sound like a homework problem... Have you covered approximate identities? The Schwarz space?

Comment: I don't have a copy of that book. _Have_ you covered approximate identities? (Those $(\phi_n)$ things where $\phi_n*f\to f$.) _Have_ you covered the Schwarz space?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yeah, all this stuff is known to me. How can we use these things here though? I guess we need to consider schwartz functions and cut these off using the formula mentioned in my question?

Comment: Answered in answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can characterize the space of integrable functions such that the Fourier transform has compact support via a Paley-Wiener sort of argument; in fact $\hat f$ has compact support if and only if $f$ is (almost everywhere) the restriction to $\Bbb R$ of an entire function $g$ with $$|g(x+iy)|\le ce^{A|y|}.$$

I don't see how this characterization helps in showing that the space is dense.  But that's not hard. Since the Fourier transform maps the Schwarz space to itself there exists a Schwarz function $\phi$ with $\int\phi=1$ such that $\hat\phi$ has compact support. (You can make $\hat\phi$ be any infinitely differentiable function with compact support.)

Define $$\phi_\delta(t)=\frac1\delta\phi\left(\frac t\delta\right).$$Then $\hat\phi_\delta$ has compact support, so if $f\in L^1$ then $\widehat{\phi_\delta*f}$ has compact support, and $||\phi_\delta*f-f||_1\to0$ as $\delta\to0$.

**Edit:** Come to think of it, it's even easier than this. For some reason I wanted a $\phi$ that gave pointwise convergence. All we need is convergence in norm, and that's much easier: We can let $\phi$ be any $L^1$ function such that $\hat \phi$ has compact support.

(So for example $\phi=\hat\psi$ where $\psi$ is just $C^2_c$, or where $\psi$ is the convolution of any two $L^2$ functions with compact support...)

Comment: nice! I somehow tried to come with an explicit example of such an $\phi$, but it seems not so easy to construct.

Comment: Well, there are various ways of constructing an infinitely differentiable function $\psi$ with compact support, some more "explicit" than others; then $\phi=\hat\psi$ works. Meanwhile see edit...

Comment: Is it possible to construct a sequence whose convergence to f is faster than the rate their supports gets larger?

Comment: @CarlLincoln _Exactly_ what do you mean by "whose convergence to f is faster than the rate their supports gets larger"?

Comment: The size of the support of $\hat{\phi}_\delta$ relative to size of support of $\hat{\phi}$ is about $1/\delta$, so as $\delta$ goes to zero the size of supports increase with the rate $1/\delta$.  My question is how about the convergence rate of L1 norm as $\delta$ does to zero in terms of $\delta$?

Comment: @CarlLincoln Regarding "the size of the support of $\hat\phi$ relative to the size of the support of $\phi$": in fact $\phi$ and $\hat\phi$ cannot both have compact support unless $\phi=0$.