# Fourier transform of a continuous function from $L^2$.

Tags: fourier-transform

Good day everyone, I have the following question. If $f$ from $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and continuous, is it true, that its Fourier transform is also continuous? It is definitely true and easy to show if $f$ in $L^1$. But what is for $L^2$?
And what if $f$ is even differentiable? Is $\hat f$ also differentiable in this case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take $f$ to be the inverse fourier transform of $\chi_{[0;1]}$. As the inverse fourier transform maps $L^2$ to $L^2$, we have $f\in L^2$. Furthermore, $\chi_{[0;1]}$ is in $L^1$, thus, $f$ is continuous. However, the fourier transform of $f$ is again $\chi_{[0;1]}$, which is not continuous.

Comment: As $\chi_{[0;1]}$ has compact support, you get that $f$ is in fact smooth. However, we have seen in the previous comment that $\hat{f}=\chi_{[0;1]}$ is not even continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition one should have is that if $f$ has a lot of decay (i.e. integrability), then $\hat{f}$ will have a lot of regularity (some $C^k$), respectively, if $f$ is very regular ($C^k$ for large $k$), then $\hat{f}$ will have a lot of decay. See for example here [Smoothness and decay property of Fourier transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206362/smoothness-and-decay-property-of-fourier-transformation)

Unfortunately, regularity of a function does not imply regularity of its Fourier transform. For example take $f=\widehat{\chi_{[-1;1]}}$. As the Fourier transform maps $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we get that $f$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. However, $\chi_{[-1;1]}$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, thus, $f$ is continuous (this is the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, see [Fourier transform is uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68642/fourier-transform-is-uniformly-continuous)). Now we can compute the Fourier transform of $f$. For this we note that $\chi_{[-1;1]}(x)=\chi_{[-1;1]}(-x)$ and therefore $\widehat{\chi_{[-1;1]}}=\check{\chi_{[-1;1]}}$ and hence

$$ \hat{f} = \widehat{\check{\chi_{[-1;1]}}} =\chi_{[-1;1]}.$$

Thus, the Fourier transform of $f$ is not even continuous.

In fact, it is much worse. Using that $\chi_{[-1;1]}$ has compact support, one can show (see [Fourier transforms having compact support](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571532/fourier-transforms-having-compact-support)) that $f$ is in fact real-analytic, even though $\hat{f}=\chi_{[-1;1]}$ is discontinuous. This is telling us that there is no hope to get differentiability of the Fourier transform just by assuming differentiability of the function.